# Can I play a single-player game alongside a multi-player party without one affecting the other?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I'm already playing a multiplayer game in BG3. What I want to know is... Can i NOW start a singe-player game by clicking NEW GAME on the main menu. If so, will this allow me to play my single-player characters without any interfence for the multiplayer game, and vice versa.

From what I read, the multi-player game exists solely on the MP server it was created on, whereas the NEW GAME gets created on your local drive. Does anyone have experience with this and could shed some light on the situation?

I basically want to play two games concurrently - singleplayer one where I AM GOD, and then a multiplayer one where we constantly play by committee and progress slower then Themberchaude heading towards the fridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea it's not an issue at all.

I got a single player game, one with my best friend, and one with her and 2 of our other friends and everything is fine :)

0 connection to eachother.